# Como pegar uma lista de objetos do JS no Controller C# MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um objeto com uma lista que vai me retornar 3 ou mais itens. Eu passo esse objeto assim:

```
 var jsonObjs = JSON.stringify(arrayObj);     
  alert(jsonObjs);      
  CarregaNotas(jsonObjs);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function CarregaNotas(notas) {
           jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                    url: "/Expedicao/Minuta/GeraNotas",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: notas,
                    success: function (data) {


                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Como pegar essa lista no controller e passar ou varrer no Model ? 
Pois para cada item eu terei que acrescentar um "And" ou "In" no "Select"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você cria uma classe com as mesmas propriedades que a que você está passando no JSON.

```
public class Obj
{
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public string Doc { get; set; }
    public string Serie { get; set; }
}
```

Na controller você pega a `stringJson` e converte em uma lista deste objeto.

```
var listaConvertida = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Obj>>(stringJson);
```

Para utilizar a classe `JsonConvert` é necessário ter o pacote NuGet `Newtonsoft.Json` instalado.